# CUDA kernel launch fails when using various offsets into input data

Tags: cuda, memory-alignment

My code is giving an error message and I am trying to track down the cause of it. To make it easier to find the problem, I have stripped away code that apparently is not relevant to causing the error message. If you can tell me why the following simple code produces an error message, then I think I should be able to fix my original code:

```
#include "cuComplex.h"
#include <cutil.h>

__device__ void compute_energy(void *data, int isample, int nsamples) {
  cuDoubleComplex * const nminusarray          = (cuDoubleComplex*)data;
  cuDoubleComplex * const f                    = (cuDoubleComplex*)(nminusarray+101);
  double          * const abs_est_errorrow_all = (double*)(f+3);
  double          * const rel_est_errorrow_all = (double*)(abs_est_errorrow_all+nsamples*51);
  int             * const iid_all              = (int*)(rel_est_errorrow_all+nsamples*51);
  int             * const iiu_all              = (int*)(iid_all+nsamples*21);
  int             * const piv_all              = (int*)(iiu_all+nsamples*21);
  cuDoubleComplex * const energyrow_all        = (cuDoubleComplex*)(piv_all+nsamples*12);
  cuDoubleComplex * const refinedenergyrow_all = (cuDoubleComplex*)(energyrow_all+nsamples*51);
  cuDoubleComplex * const btplus_all           = (cuDoubleComplex*)(refinedenergyrow_all+nsamples*51);

  cuDoubleComplex * const btplus           = btplus_all+isample*21021;

  btplus[0] = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0, 0.0);
}

__global__ void computeLamHeight(void *data, int nlambda) {
  compute_energy(data, blockIdx.x, nlambda);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  void *device_data;

  CUT_DEVICE_INIT(argc, argv);
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMalloc(&device_data, 184465640));
  computeLamHeight<<<dim3(101, 1, 1), dim3(512, 1, 1), 45000>>>(device_data, 101);
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaThreadSynchronize());
}
```

I am using a GeForce GTX 480 and I am compiling the code like so:

```
nvcc -L /soft/cuda-sdk/4.0.17/C/lib -I /soft/cuda-sdk/4.0.17/C/common/inc -lcutil_x86_64 -arch sm_13 -O3 -Xopencc "-Wall" Main.cu
```

The output is:

```
Using device 0: GeForce GTX 480
Cuda error in file 'Main.cu' in line 31 : unspecified launch failure.
```

EDIT: I have now further simplified the code. The following simpler code still produces the error message:

```
#include <cutil.h>

__global__ void compute_energy(void *data) {
  *(double*)((int*)data+101) = 0.0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  void *device_data;

  CUT_DEVICE_INIT(argc, argv);
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMalloc(&device_data, 101*sizeof(int)+sizeof(double)));
  compute_energy<<<dim3(1, 1, 1), dim3(1, 1, 1)>>>(device_data);
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaThreadSynchronize());
}
```

Now it is easy to see that the offset should be valid. I tried running cuda-memcheck and it says the following:

```
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
Using device 0: GeForce GTX 480
Cuda error in file 'Main.cu' in line 13 : unspecified launch failure.
========= Invalid __global__ write of size 8
=========     at 0x00000020 in compute_energy
=========     by thread (0,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x200200194 is misaligned
=========
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 1 error
```

I tried searching the internet to find what is meant by the address being misaligned, but I failed to find an explanation. What is the deal?

Comment: There is a utility called cuda-memcheck in the toolkit which will show you exactly where the problem is occurring by flagging out of bounds memory accesses, which is the likely error here.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. cuda-memcheck says that the address is misaligned. Unfortunately, I fail to find an explanation when I search the internet for that. I have simplified my code so that it is clear that the memory access is not out of bounds; apparently the problem is something else. Please examine my edit to my question. Can you explain please? Thank you!

Comment: CUDA 4.2 Programming Guide, section 5.3.2.1 Global Memory:
Global memory resides in device memory and device memory is accessed via 32-, 64-, or 128-byte memory transactions. These memory transactions must be naturally aligned: Only the 32-, 64-, or 128-byte segments of device memory that are aligned to their size (i.e. whose first address is a multiple of their size) can be read or written by memory transactions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was very hard to parse your original code with all of those magic constants, but your updated repro case makes the problem immediately obvious. The GPU architecture requires all pointers to be aligned to word boundaries. Your kernel contains a pointer access which is not correctly word aligned. Doubles are an 64 bit type, and your addressing is not aligned to an even 64 bit boundary. This:

```
*(double*)((int*)data+100) = 0.0; // 50th double
```

or this:

```
*(double*)((int*)data+102) = 0.0; // 51st double
```

are both legal. This:

```
*(double*)((int*)data+101) = 0.0; // not aligned to a 64 bit boundary
```

is not.

Comment: This was my problem - structure that was not word aligned. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

the error indicates out of bound memory access, please check the offset value.